# Emacs 25: org-mode fontification error

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, font-lock

There are two other questions asking this, but one accepted an answer that didn't help, and the other lacked detail.

To reproduce:

- Ubuntu 14.04 running emacs-snapshot from `ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-elisp/ppa/ubuntu`
- Fire up `emacs -Q`.
- `M-x org-version` => `Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/org/)`
- `M-x emacs-version` => `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2015-10-26`
- eval `(setq org-src-fontify-natively 't)`

Then make a tiny example:

```
* Simple Program
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE ruby
  puts("foo")
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Voila: in the message buffer `org-mode fontification error [15 times]`.

How can I fix the fontification, so my buffers look pretty and my exports work?

Comment: I have seen this issue once but it got resolved. I believe it was due to mixed installations of org-mode versions. But I am not sure; and also you mentioned that you see this in `emacs -Q` session.

Comment: Seeing the same problem. Using org-plus-contrib installed from org site with emacs 25.2.  Have ensured the org-plus-contrib package is loaded before anything uses org mode, so can't see anything which would result in the build-n/GNU version being loaded and thus causing conflicts. Anyone able to enlighten me on what they did to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've narrowed this down (at least for my case). the problem appears to be with goto-address-prog-mode. Below is a minimal init.el which will load the latest org-plus-contrib from org and a simple test.org file. I start emacs with

```
/usr/local/bin/emacs -q -l ./init.el --debug-init
```

and will get the org-mode fontification error message when I open test.org. Remove the hook line to load goto-address-prog-mode and all is OK. If I use the org-mode which comes with emcas 25.1, no error.

The init file is

```
(require 'package)

(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'org-plus-contrib)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'org-plus-contrib))

(require 'org)

(require 'goto-addr)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'goto-address-prog-mode)
```

and the test.org file is simply

```
 * Test   
   This is a simple test org file

   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
     (message "A Test")  
   #+END_SRC
```

This is emacs 25.1 running on Ubuntu built from the tarball.

GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
of 2017-02-25